# How to import Data from Google Sheet into MongoDB Atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, google-sheets, mongodb-atlas

I need to import Data from Google Sheet into MongoDB Atlas. Is there any possible way?

The Google sheet:
[image]

The mongo atlas cluster:
[image]

Comment: Google Sheet --> export to CSV --> `mongoimport` to MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: Yes............